# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myquerystring) removes = sign from string

Tags: asp.net

debugging: WHERE%20(1%20=%201)%20%20AND%20(village%20=%20'Amsterdam')

### My exact query string is:

WHERE ( 1 = 1 ) AND (village = 'Amsterdam')

### the result is:

WHERE ( 1  1 ) AND (village = 'Amsterdam')

### Why ist the first = removed ?

### second try :

WHERE ( null is null ) AND (village = 'Amsterdam')

### the result is: (second = is removed)

WHERE ( null is null ) AND (village 'Amsterdam')

### My environment:

VS2010, ASP.NET 4.0, SQL-Server 2008, unicode8

### here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var qs = this.ClientQueryString;
  NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (String s in qscoll.AllKeys)
  {
    sb.Append(s + qscoll[s]);
  }

  string sWhere = sb.ToString();

  // ...
}
```

### THANKS for your supports ! this works fine

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var qs = this.ClientQueryString;
  var sQuery = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(qs);
  //...
}
```

Comment: Are sure about the "exact" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query strings must be percent encoded. Your query string is not. "=" can not appear in query string data parts. It is always encoded into %3D.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Btw, using query strings to send sql queries is not secure and very often result in security breaches.

Comment: while I debugging there is a = sign: WHERE%20(1%20=%201)%20%20AND%20(village%20=%20'Amsterdam')

Comment: then you didn't encode this url properly (you or the person who sent it).

Comment: Thank you very much Softlion, I post my solution.

Comment: @KolaSiro Until someone sees you using SQL in your querystring and starts adding their own SQL code like `; DROP TABLE Users;--`

Answer (score 0):

HttpUtility.ParseQueryString parses the [querystring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of a URL. It has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: Thanx, for your fast response. I'll try to remove the SQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` Parses a (HTTP) query string into a `NameValueCollection` and has nothing to do with the SQL statements that you write.